# Joomla K2 Extra Field IMAGE not showing in Latest_items category (Template overrides)

Tags: php, categories, k2

I'm working for hours for just a small code. I still don't understand why it does not work, or better, why the image are not showing.

I have the latest k2 version. (Joomla 3)

As you can see, in the item page, you will see there **"Additional Info"**. Well, i want to add this in **Latest_items** category.

*This is the code in item.php (Additional Info)*

```
<div class="itemExtraFields">
    <h3><?php echo JText::_('K2_ADDITIONAL_INFO'); ?></h3>
    <ul>
        <?php foreach ($this->item->extra_fields as $key=>$extraField): ?>
        <?php if($extraField->value != ''): ?>
        <li class="<?php echo ($key%2) ? "odd" : "even"; ?> type<?php echo ucfirst($extraField->type); ?> group<?php echo $extraField->group; ?>">
            <?php if($extraField->type == 'header'): ?>
            <h4 class="itemExtraFieldsHeader"><?php echo $extraField->name; ?></h4>
            <?php else: ?>
            <span class="itemExtraFieldsLabel"><?php echo $extraField->name; ?>:</span> <span class="itemExtraFieldsValue"><?php echo $extraField->value; ?></span>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </li>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

If i place this in Latest_items.php, what I get is all in text. https://i.stack.imgur.com/j2Pnz.png

That's because the **span**

So, what i did is nothing hard, just replaced the span to img:

```
<?php if($this->item->params->get('catItemExtraFields') && count($this->item->extra_fields)): ?>
<div class="matches_logo_li">
    <h4>-</h4>
    <ul>
    <?php foreach ($this->item->extra_fields as $key=>$extraField): ?>
    <?php if($extraField->value != ''): ?>          
        <li class="<?php echo ($key%2) ? "odd" : "even"; ?> type<?php echo ucfirst($extraField->type); ?> group<?php echo $extraField->group; ?>">
            <img class="itemExtraFieldsValue" src="<?php echo $extraField->value; ?>">
        </li>
    <?php endif; ?>                                 
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
    <?php if(isset($extrafields[4]) === true):?>
        <li>
            <span class="itemExtraFieldsValue" > 
                <?php echo $extraField->value; ?>
            </span>
        </li>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

This is what i want: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aw633.png

But it's just not right to work with **id** and **img**, i need more fields and i can't add every time a new id field php code and the **itemExtraFieldsLabel**, name of extra field, is also not showing.

If i place a new field, just a textfield like the date 14/08/2015 then its show as a image that can't be founded and thats right because i changed the tag to IMG.

But since I've added an id code of the field, can say that its working.

```
    <?php if(isset($extrafields[4]) === true):?>
        <li>
            <span class="itemExtraFieldsValue" > 
                <?php echo $extraField->value; ?>
            </span>
        </li>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

But as I said, I can not work with id.

Someone need to help my with this. I think itsn't hard but i can not do this and it is strange that the image is not showing as span tag as it works in item.php.

**EDIT:**

my whole code don't want to show without this code:

```
<!--
    <?php $extra = json_decode($item->extra_fields); ?>
<?php if (isset($this->item->extra_fields)) : ?>
  <div class="catItemExtraFields">
    <ul>
    <?php if (is_string($this->item->extra_fields)) {
        $this->item->extra_fields = json_decode($this->item->extra_fields);
      }
      foreach ($this->item->extra_fields as $key=>$extraField) {
        if ($extraField->value != '') {
          echo "<li>".$extraField->name.": ".$extraField->value."</li>";
        }
      }
    ?>
    </ul>
  </div>
<?php endif; ?> -->
```

Someone really need to help my!

Regards